# Cannot open files with accents using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, filenames, diacritics

I try to read all the files in a directory, but as they contain spaces and accents, I get errors (already read many posts on SO but cannot find any answer)

this returns a list of files

```
files = [y for x in os.walk(".") for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.pdf'))]
```

but as I try to open them one by one

```
for file in files:
    with open(file,"r") as f:
```

I get these kind of errors (I obfuscated the letters cos it's confidential):

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '.\abcd?efgh (hijk? lmnop).pdf'
```

I believe the issues are caused by the accents but since it's python that gives me the the file names, I dont understand why they are not compatible with "open()"

regards

how can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you try it with `os.walk(u'.')`?

Comment: you're the man !!! it worked, thank you so much

Comment: What platform are you on? If it's not Windows, this could be a sign of a deeper problem with your filesystems or mount tables that you should fix or you might see other problems later.

Comment: Also, why are you using `glob` on the results of `walk`? Why not `file for root, dirs, files in os.walk(u'.') for file in files if os.path.splitext(file) == '.pdf'`?

Comment: *"... caused by the accents"* - I believe they are called *[diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)* (assuming more than just the accent is giving you trouble).

Answer (score 0):

I do this now :

```
files = [y for x in os.walk(u'.') for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.'+extension))]
```

Note the use of `u'.'` instead of `"."`

Comment: You also want `u'*.'`. And you probably also want `extension` to be a `unicode` rather than a `str`.